# CSS Transition div container height from 100% to 200%

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've read a few other questions, but I've yet to come across a solid example of transitioning a div with it's natural height (auto, 100%), into a larger height (say 200%) when a user hovers over it. Any solid technique?

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ESgna/3

```
.critic-quotes {
    -webkit-transition: max-height 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: max-height 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: max-height 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: max-height 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: max-height 0.3s ease-in-out;
    max-height: 100%;

}

.critic-quotes:hover {
    max-height: 200%;
  }
```

Comment: the problem with that one is I have to set the `div`'s max-height, is there a way to just make it `auto` or `100%`?

Comment: Because `height: 100%` is not a property that browsers calculate. Browsers just vertically append more children elements to the parent element, without specifying the exact height value. This is also the reason why we cannot make equal-height columns by setting `height: 100%;`. And `transition` needs *exact value* to calculate the animation. Therefore `max-height` does not work. Still we can nudge browsers to calculate the exact natural height by explicitly call JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ESgna/5/)**

**Previously**

```
.critic-quotes:hover {
    max-height: 200%;
  }
```

**Update:**

```
.critic-quotes {
    -webkit-transition: max-height 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: max-height 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: max-height 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: max-height 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: max-height 0.3s ease-in-out;
    max-height: 100%;

}

.critic-quotes:hover{
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(2);
          transform: scaleY(2);
}
```

Comment: An explanation about "why the previous code wasn't working?" isn't a bad idea, is it?

Comment: I don't want to scale everything though, just expand the height of the container.